# script colors to solarized

Tags: colorscheme, macos, plugin-solarized

using macOS, I've colored the Terminal app by importing the [Solarized](https://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/) theme but the scripts I write inside the terminal are not displayed in the Solarized theme. `:colorscheme="default"`

[image]

While [Solarized looks like this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/altercation/solarized/master/img/screen-shell-dark.png).

I can use `:colorscheme TAB` to find/use Solarized but it just creates an awful highlight effect:

[image]

I've been using my build ([vimSimple](https://github.com/todd-dsm/vimSimple)) for years and this issue has never occurred. The only thing that's changed is I've upgraded to macOS Catalina. These files are just softlinked:

```
ls -al
...
lrwxr-xr-x   1 USER staff    32 May 21 14:47 .vim -> /Users/USER/code/vimsimple/vim
-rw-------   1 USER staff 26249 May 27 12:15 .viminfo
lrwxr-xr-x   1 USER staff    34 May 21 15:00 .vimrc -> /Users/USER/code/vimsimple/vimrc
...
```

I've tried some of the suggestions from [filed issues](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized/issues/166) but no luck. If anyone can help get past this that would be bomb.

Comment: Based on [the project's page](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized) and the way vim works, you need to install solarized for vim (using a plugin manager, packages, or something else) and then put a couple of instructions in your vimrc...

Comment: Does `:set termguicolors` fix it?

Comment: I just spotted [https://github.com/todd-dsm/vimSimple/blob/master/vim/vimrcs/colors.vim](https://github.com/todd-dsm/vimSimple/blob/master/vim/vimrcs/colors.vim)... you need to set the `g:` variable prior to `color` for it to have any effect. But I also didn't see it get sourced anywhere. Plus, if you have your terminal setup with the solarized palette, you don't need it. I did find it worked better in MacVim, though (tried in term w/o solarized palette)

Comment: @filbranden sadly no, I read the help and checked that vim was compiled with that feature (it is). When setting it, it just made the screen more blah:
https://imgur.com/a/xMstl3D

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, should have put that install detail in the original post. I download the whole package, extract it, then open the Terminal > Preferences > Profiles > Gear > Import: solarized/osx-terminal.app-colors-solarized/xterm-256color/Solarized\ Dark\ xterm-256color.terminal.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble; after that, I install vim-colors-solarized: (pathogen)
https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized#option-2-pathogen-installation-recommended

Not sure why both are necessary. This is where my vim gets away from me.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble; not sure where you're getting the `g:` `color` bit. The only config I dropped in is this one. Basically copy/pasted:
https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized#modify-vimrc

Comment: @todd_dsm both are necessary because vim colorschemes that dont use termguicolors use the terminal’s color palette; aligning them makes a big difference. What I was saying is `let g:...` needs to happen before `colorscheme ...` to have an effect.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, just tried with `let g:colorscheme=solarized` and no luck. There's something truly bizarre going on.

Comment: @todd_dsm colorscheme is not the variable I’m talking about. What about solarized_termcolors in the file I linked to?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble; sorry, I see what you mean now. I've moved it up above the rest. Now it has a chocolaty look to it. But, on the upside, it's the only thing that's caused a change so far :-)
https://imgur.com/a/w1ZAmx4

Comment: @todd_dsm that looks “pretty right”—it wont be perfect without either termguicolors or a graphical vim.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble; you can see here it's way off target: https://imgur.com/gallery/HCPsPPm. Just checked my work laptop; it has the same vimSimple config (github above) running properly for 6 months. I used the same automation to install on my personal laptop last week. I tar'd-up the vim config on the work laptop, transferred it to the personal laptop and the issue persists. Starting to think there's an environmental issue as well.